# Why can't I use a table alias in a subquery?

Tags: join, ms-access, table-alias

I have a MS Access database. When I try to run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM tblClients AS a1 
  LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 lVersion, lRequestID AS lVerReqId, lClientId    
    FROM tblClientsVersionsHistory 
    WHERE ID = (
      SELECT MAX(ID) 
      FROM tblClientsVersionsHistory 
      WHERE lClientId = a1.Id
    )
  ) AS a2
  ON a1.Id = a2.lClientId
)
```

It suggest me to enter `a1.Id`, but I want to use it from `(SELECT * FROM tblClients AS a1)`.

Comment: MS Access does not support volatile references. Use additional subquery instead.

Comment: Akina, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `a1` alias belongs to a table to which the `a2` derived table is being joined, and you are trying to reference the alias from inside the derived table. You cannot do that in SQL. This is not just a limitation of MS Access.

If it was a correlated subquery and the alias in question was assigned at any of the outer levels, such a reference would be valid, but a derived table is not allowed to reference aliases of any of the tables it is being joined to. You *may* reference them in the derived table's `ON` joining predicate. In this case, `a1.Id` is a valid reference in `ON a1.Id = a2.lClientId`, and it would be equally valid if it was used in a correlated subquery in the `ON` clause, for instance:

```
ON EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      ... something something ...
      ... a1.Id ...
      ...
  )
```

That would work.  But such references cannot be resolved inside the derived table itself. As a result, you cannot reference `a1` inside `a2`.